# I want to know which process open() the "Kernel Device Driver"

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I am using the following Kernel Device Driver.

```
    /**
     * @file   ebbchar.c
     * @author Derek Molloy
     * @date   7 April 2015
     * @version 0.1
     * @brief   An introductory character driver to support the second article of my series on
     * Linux loadable kernel module (LKM) development. This module maps to /dev/ebbchar and
     * comes with a helper C program that can be run in Linux user space to communicate with
     * this the LKM.
     * @see http://www.derekmolloy.ie/ for a full description and follow-up descriptions.
     */

    #include <linux/init.h>           // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
    #include <linux/module.h>         // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
    #include <linux/device.h>         // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
    #include <linux/kernel.h>         // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
    #include <linux/fs.h>             // Header for the Linux file system support
    #include <asm/uaccess.h>          // Required for the copy to user function
    #define  DEVICE_NAME "ebbchar"    ///< The device will appear at /dev/ebbchar using this value
    #define  CLASS_NAME  "ebb"        ///< The device class -- this is a character device driver

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");            ///< The license type -- this affects available functionality
    MODULE_AUTHOR("Derek Molloy");    ///< The author -- visible when you use modinfo
    MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver for the BBB");  ///< The description -- see modinfo
    MODULE_VERSION("0.1");            ///< A version number to inform users

    static int    majorNumber;                  ///< Stores the device number -- determined automatically
    static char   message[256] = {0};           ///< Memory for the string that is passed from userspace
    static short  size_of_message;              ///< Used to remember the size of the string stored
    static int    numberOpens = 0;              ///< Counts the number of times the device is opened
    static struct class*  ebbcharClass  = NULL; ///< The device-driver class struct pointer
    static struct device* ebbcharDevice = NULL; ///< The device-driver device struct pointer

    // The prototype functions for the character driver -- must come before the struct definition
    static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
    static int     dev_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
    static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
    static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

    /** @brief Devices are represented as file structure in the kernel. The file_operations structure from
     *  /linux/fs.h lists the callback functions that you wish to associated with your file operations
     *  using a C99 syntax structure. char devices usually implement open, read, write and release calls
     */
    static struct file_operations fops =
    {
       .open = dev_open,
       .read = dev_read,
       .write = dev_write,
       .release = dev_release,
    };

    /** @brief The LKM initialization function
     *  The static keyword restricts the visibility of the function to within this C file. The __init
     *  macro means that for a built-in driver (not a LKM) the function is only used at initialization
     *  time and that it can be discarded and its memory freed up after that point.
     *  @return returns 0 if successful
     */
    static int __init ebbchar_init(void){
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM\n");

       // Try to dynamically allocate a major number for the device -- more difficult but worth it
       majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
       if (majorNumber<0){
          printk(KERN_ALERT "EBBChar failed to register a major number\n");
          return majorNumber;
       }
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);

       // Register the device class
       ebbcharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
       if (IS_ERR(ebbcharClass)){                // Check for error and clean up if there is
          unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
          return PTR_ERR(ebbcharClass);          // Correct way to return an error on a pointer
       }
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class registered correctly\n");

       // Register the device driver
       ebbcharDevice = device_create(ebbcharClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
       if (IS_ERR(ebbcharDevice)){               // Clean up if there is an error
          class_destroy(ebbcharClass);           // Repeated code but the alternative is goto statements
          unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
          printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create the device\n");
          return PTR_ERR(ebbcharDevice);
       }
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class created correctly\n"); // Made it! device was initialized
       return 0;
    }

    /** @brief The LKM cleanup function
     *  Similar to the initialization function, it is static. The __exit macro notifies that if this
     *  code is used for a built-in driver (not a LKM) that this function is not required.
     */
    static void __exit ebbchar_exit(void){
       device_destroy(ebbcharClass, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0));     // remove the device
       class_unregister(ebbcharClass);                          // unregister the device class
       class_destroy(ebbcharClass);                             // remove the device class
       unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);             // unregister the major number
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Goodbye from the LKM!\n");
    }

    /** @brief The device open function that is called each time the device is opened
     *  This will only increment the numberOpens counter in this case.
     *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
     *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
     */
    static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
       numberOpens++;
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
       return 0;
    }

    /** @brief This function is called whenever device is being read from user space i.e. data is
     *  being sent from the device to the user. In this case is uses the copy_to_user() function to
     *  send the buffer string to the user and captures any errors.
     *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
     *  @param buffer The pointer to the buffer to which this function writes the data
     *  @param len The length of the b
     *  @param offset The offset if required
     */
    static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
       int error_count = 0;
       // copy_to_user has the format ( * to, *from, size) and returns 0 on success
       error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, message, size_of_message);

       if (error_count==0){            // if true then have success
          printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Sent %d characters to the user\n", size_of_message);
          return (size_of_message=0);  // clear the position to the start and return 0
       }
       else {
          printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Failed to send %d characters to the user\n", error_count);
          return -EFAULT;              // Failed -- return a bad address message (i.e. -14)
       }
    }

    /** @brief This function is called whenever the device is being written to from user space i.e.
     *  data is sent to the device from the user. The data is copied to the message[] array in this
     *  LKM using the sprintf() function along with the length of the string.
     *  @param filep A pointer to a file object
     *  @param buffer The buffer to that contains the string to write to the device
     *  @param len The length of the array of data that is being passed in the const char buffer
     *  @param offset The offset if required
     */
    static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
       sprintf(message, "%s(%zu letters)", buffer, len);   // appending received string with its length
       size_of_message = strlen(message);                 // store the length of the stored message
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Received %zu characters from the user\n", len);
       return len;
    }

    /** @brief The device release function that is called whenever the device is closed/released by
     *  the userspace program
     *  @param inodep A pointer to an inode object (defined in linux/fs.h)
     *  @param filep A pointer to a file object (defined in linux/fs.h)
     */
    static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device successfully closed\n");
       return 0;
    }

    /** @brief A module must use the module_init() module_exit() macros from linux/init.h, which
     *  identify the initialization function at insertion time and the cleanup function (as
     *  listed above)
     */
    module_init(ebbchar_init);
    module_exit(ebbchar_exit);
```

When I open the device driver in User Space, the dev_open() function is executed.

```
    static struct file_operations fops =
    {
       .open = dev_open,
       .read = dev_read,
       .write = dev_write,
       .release = dev_release,
    };

    static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
       numberOpens++;
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
       return 0;
    }
```

I want to know who has open() the Device Driver node (/dev/ebbchar).
When a process calls the dev_open() function of the device driver, I want to debug the process name via printk().
What should I do?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915728/getting-user-process-pid-when-writing-linux-kernel-module

Comment: @JohanMyréen Wow! You also answered my http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347001/is-the-pid-of-kernel-panic-the-killer-of-kernel-panic/347008#347008. I Love You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Johan Myréen` gave me the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915728/getting-user-process-pid-when-writing-linux-kernel-module
So I was able to debug as below.

```
    static int dev_open(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep){
       numberOpens++;
       printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Device has been opened %d time(s)\n", numberOpens);
           printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
           printk("The process id is %d\n", (int) task_pid_nr(current));
           printk("The process vid is %d\n", (int) task_pid_vnr(current));
           printk("The process name is %s\n", current->comm);
           printk("The process tty is %d\n", current->signal->tty);
           printk("The process group is %d\n", (int) task_tgid_nr(current));
           printk("\n\n");
       return 0;
    }
```

In User Space, the following confirmation is made.

```
    root@Test:~# ./ebbchar_open
    EBBChar: Device has been opened 1 time(s)
    Loading Module
    The process id is 458
    The process vid is 458
    The process name is ebbchar_open
    The process tty is -294157312
    The process group is 458
```

`Johan Myréen` Thanks!